# A question about geometry of plane curve books

Tags: plane-curves

I can't study algebraic geometry yet, so before i learn that, yet i need a comprehensive treatment to the geometric theory of plane curves. i notice that the books refer to this subject either out of print thick one or not comprehensive thin books. I also notice that for the old ones, geometric construction is often missing. Is there any introductory(beginning undergradutes) to intermediate(advanced undergraduates or beginning graduates) comprehensive thick books about theory of plane curves that are free online(i prefer this, but if it is a old one, i prefer that it have more graph so it gives me much more intuition) and the good ones that are not out of print(please give the content of the books if preview is unavailable), also a curious question is, why colleges doesn't offer a plane curve course that stand alone by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few books:

- BRIESKORN, KNORRER, *Plane algebraic curves*.
- FULTON, [*Algebraic curves, an introduction to algebraic geometry*](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf).
- KUNZ, *Introduction to plane algebraic curves*.
- WALKER, *Algebraic curves*.

Comment: Those seems too advanced for me and is there books focus more on geometric construction?

Comment: +1 for give some example althrough those seems inaccessible

Comment: @Victor, I'm not sure what level you want to read. There is no advanced book on plain Euclidean geometric constructions. For advanced books on geometry beyond school geometry try the list [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/107889/589).

Comment: @Ihf - Curves are consider part of Euclidean geometry? If the answer is yes, then what is a free online book that is forcus on curves?

Comment: Perhaps you want [A Catalog of Special Plane Curves](http://www.amazon.com/A-Catalog-Special-Plane-Curves/dp/0486602885).