# A good book on basic (Euclidean) geometry.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

We were studying **demonstrative geometry**, so I thought if I read *Euclid's Elements* it would give me the proper conceptual basis to understand the theorems. But then I learned that Euclid's method of proving congruence is not accepted today and many of his propositions have no axioms to support them; so I am left where I started.

I want to read a good book that teaches the basics of **Euclidean geometry** pretty much like *Euclid's Elements* but does not use analysis or advanced mathematical methods, just simple geometrical theorems. Also, it should be rigorous and consistent with today's standards.

Some people might recognize this as a duplicate so let me just add one more thing; it should be able to be understood by any student with secondary level education. *Euclid's Elements* may not be rigorous but I was still able to understand it easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107882/geometry-book-recommendation.

Comment: I would suggest not to be quite so quick to dismiss Euclid. Yes, he leaves certain principles unstated: axioms, or postulates, or definitions. But understanding his proofs, which are otherwise rock solid, is an excellent way to understand, in conjunction with other readings, just what Euclid missed.

Comment: @lhf I added a little at the end. I hope you will forgive me. ; )

Comment: @LeeMosher I am not dismissing Euclid. His book is still universal, but the problem is I want to know proofs to simple postulates as the SAS in way I can understand. I am sure there must be some good books on basic geometry.

Answer (score 1):

refer to Robin hartsthorne: Geometry, Euclid and Beyond. No need to endorse this book!

Comment: Could you also provide a PDF link?