# Modern Geometry Textbook

Tags: euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

What's a good introduction (undergrad level) to modern axiomatic geometry?  By that I mean Euclidean geometry, but using a more modern set of axioms such as Hilbert's or Tarski's.

Comment: Have you tried Hartshorne's "Geometry: Euclid and beyond"? There's a good 75 pages about Hilbert's axioms in there, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: How are you using it? because a classical one is Coxeter's Revised Geoemtry

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/107889/589.

Answer (score 0):

Elemental Differential Geometry by Christian Bar has a good introduction to the axioms of Euclidean Geometry, although it swiftly moves on to non-Euclidean Geometry (as you would expect). This would be my preferred text for the axioms of Euclidean Geometry and for taking the subject further I would recommend Roger Johnson's Advanced Euclidean Geometry - old-fashioned but very good.