# In depth Geometry books with heavy focus on proofs

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a very in depth geometry book that has a heavy focus on proofs. Geometry's my favorite subject, so I don't mind difficulty or deviations from the "normal" type of geometry. I also don't mind focus on different types of geometry.
I'm fine with any. I'm just bored and geometry struck me as the one thing really fun to do. I do know most topics till calculus.

Comment: I'm fine with any. I'm just bored and geometry struck me as the one thing really fun to do. I do know most topics till calculus.

Comment: There is analytical geometry, euclidean geometry at most basic level. Then there are so many other types of geometries. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107882/geometry-book-recommendation

Comment: Geometry Revisited by Coxeter is supposed to be good, but I haven’t read it myself.

Comment: If you are interested in classical Euclidean geometry developed rigorously from axioms (with a sprinkling of non-Euclidean) I'd recommend John Lee's "Axiomatic Geometry".

Comment: [This](https://ohioopen.library.ohio.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=opentextbooks) comes from the OHIO Open Library.