# Can you recommend a high school analytic geometry book/online notes?

Tags: analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

Can you recommend a high school analytic geometry book/online notes? There should be line, area, euquation of line, equation circle, vectors, vectors in the plane, conics, Cartesian coordinate system in the plane, vectors, properties of vectors, scalar product of vectors, vector projection. Translation and rotation of axes. Polar coordinates. Line, circle and conics (ellipse, parabola, hyperbola) in the plane. Rectangular coordinates in space, vectors, vector product. Cylindrical and spherical coordinates. Lines and planes in space. Second-degree (quadric) surfaces (ellipsoid, paraboloid, hyperboloid, conic, cylinder). etc in context as high school level (it can be undergraduate level).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2489240/353218

Answer (score 0):

Open Stax has a variety of texts, available freely.

https://openstax.org/details/precalculus should cover much of this material.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic Geometry Charles H. Lehman

Comment: I couldn't this as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Geometria Analitica by Charles H. Lehman

Free PDF download here (Spanish version only):

https://www.cimat.mx/ciencia_para_jovenes/bachillerato/libros/[Lehmann]GeometriaAnalitica.pdf

This is the book I used in my second year of High School in Mexico. I always thought this book was originally written in English and then translated into Spanish. However, I do not think it was ever published in English.