# Undergraduate Introduction to Modern Geometry - What to expect?

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation, noneuclidean-geometry

I'm currently an undergraduate who is deciding which courses to take next semester. A course that a professor recommended is Introduction to Modern Geometry (description provided below) partially because my school isn't offering Abstract Algebra, or Differential Geometry both of which I'd be interested in taking and partially because he thinks I can use the challenge. My qualm is that I'm not exactly sure what it is because the description seems vague and I'm not sure how it can be used whereas I'm more familiar with the types of math I mentioned. Also I can't find study resources for the course which is worrisome as I don't always intuitively get explanations my professors give. The majority of posts I see are about Euclidean geometries which it seems this isn't.

If someone is more familiar with the course and can give insights and/or recommend books to study from it would be appreciated. Thank you!

(Course description)

Topic to be discussed include logical deficiencies in Euclidean geometry, Euclid’s parallel postulate, an introduction to non-Euclidean geometries, the theory of incidence, and the theory of order on the line.

Comment: Greenberg, euclidean and non-euclidean geometries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Books on classical geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13735/books-on-classical-geometry). Also searching with ‘[book-recommendation][geometry]’ yields a ton of hits which probably already answer your question.